# Can the Facebook Graph API supply me an array of friends who use an app I created?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to find any information that shows how I can get a list of friends who use a facebook app I created. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the follow FQL query:

```
SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE has_added_app=1 
and uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

This will be better than using the deprecated old REST api method.

Comment: Has anyone found a way to accomplish this directly with the Graph API? I'd like to avoid FQL if at all possible since I've had trouble with it in the past when used in conjunction with the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Think this is what you are looking for : [friends.getAppUsers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/friends.getAppUsers/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use GET method to retrieve the json object

```
    $friends = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$fbid/friends?access_token=" . $cookie['access_token']), true);
    $friends = $friends['data'];
    foreach($friends as $a => $b) {
    $the_id = $b['id'];
    echo $b['name'];
    }
```